# NetSuite Saved Search - Highlight based on 'Results' not 'Criteria'

Tags: netsuite

How can I create a 'Highlight if..." condition based off a results formula and not saved search criteria? For instance, in my saved search I have a results formula doing some addition in one column. I would like to highlight the row if my formula is greater than zero.

I am running into trouble because it seems as if I can only create a 'Highlight if...' condition solely based off my search criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're on the "Highlight if... (Summary)" tab (to the right of "Highlight if..." under Highlighting) if you're using a summary formula.  Be aware that you need to drill in about 3 windows deep when on this tab and NetSuite is very picky about exactly what you select at each step.  The good news is that your formula itself is working fine - I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the formula from your results to a formula in the highlight criteria.  You do have to repeat the formula but it works just fine

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. However, the formula works fine in the results column.  sum(case when {type} IN ('Item Fulfillment', 'Invoice','Cash Sale') then {quantity}else 0 end + case when {type} = 'Credit Memo' then {quantity} else 0 end + Case when {type} = 'Item Receipt' and {createdfrom.type} = 'Vendor Return Authorization' then {quantity} else 0 end) - (MAX(NVL({item.quantityavailable},0)) + max(NVL({item.quantityonorder},0)))